# Stub Net::POP3.start

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, email-parsing

Im writing a test for a worker which goes and gets emails then does something with them:

```
Net::POP3.start('pop.gmail.com', 995, "xxx", "xxxx") do |pop|
  if pop.mails.empty?
    log "#{Time.now} No mail."
  else
    pop.each_mail do |mail|
      #do something
    end
  end
end
```

What is the best way to stub `Net::POP3.start` in such a way that it will return similar data should it actually run?

Thanks

Dickie

Edit:

The rest of the job/filling in the `#do something` looks a little like this:

```
Net::POP3.start('pop.gmail.com', 995, "xxx", "xxxx") do |pop|
  if pop.mails.empty?
    log "#{Time.now} No mail."
  else
    pop.each_mail do |mail|
      parse_mail mail.pop
    end
  end
end


def parse_mail(raw_email)
   email = Mail.new raw_email
   email.attachments
   email.from
   email.subject
end
```

The solution I came up with is(which may be a bit specific for your needs):

```
Net::POP3.stub(:start).and_yield Net::POP3.new("a test string")
Net::POP3.any_instance.stub(:mails).and_return [Net::POPMail.new("test","test","test","test")]
Net::POPMail.any_instance.stub(:pop).and_return("a raw email string")
```

Which I don't really like.

Refactoring it using some of the techniques @SteveTurczyn is using.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "happy path" of several emails...

```
require 'spec_helper'
module NET 
  module POP3
  end
end
describe "testing NET::POP3" do
  before do
    @mail1 = double('mail1')
    @mail2 = double('mail2')
    @mail3 = double('mail3')
    @pop = double('pop')
    @pop.stub_chain(:mails, :empty?).and_return false
    allow(@pop).to receive(:each_mail).and_yield(@mail1).and_yield(@mail2).and_yield(@mail3) 
    expect(NET::POP3).to receive(:start).and_yield(@pop)
  end
  describe "three emails pending" do
    it "will return a pop entity" do
      NET::POP3.start do |p|
        expect(p).to eq(@pop)
      end
    end
    it "pop will indicate that emails are not empty" do
      NET::POP3.start do |p|
        expect(p.mails.empty?).to be_false
      end
    end
    it "pop will contain three mails" do
      NET::POP3.start do |p|
        counter = 0
        p.each_mail do |m|
          counter += 1
          expect([@mail1, @mail2, @mail3]).to include(m)
        end
        expect(counter).to eq 3
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I probably should have been more clearer in what I was doing with the email. I am processing attachments to the email. In the end my solution was not too dissimilar to yours. Although I prefer the way you have done it. Ill post my solution then an updated solution.